# Data grid view not displaying the updated data in win form c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Okay so I have this datagridview that is connected to the database in access through the data source and it is fine but when I add another row in the table from a form and when I return back to the form having the datagridview it only shows the previous values, not the newly added values.

Even After I restart/ re-run the application. It keeps on happening.

Btw, I am using a AutoFilter feature by following this link 
[AutoFilter in DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx)

**Here is the .cs file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DataGridViewAutoFilter;

namespace Call_Logger
{
public partial class AutoFilter : Form
{
    public AutoFilter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void AutoFilter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the    'datasetFilter.LogCall' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

       this.logCallTableAdapter.Fill(this.datasetFilter.LogCall);

    }

    private void showAllLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn.RemoveFilter(dataGridView1);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {

        String filterStatus = DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell.GetFilterStatus(dataGridView1);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterStatus))
        {
            showAllLabel.Visible = false;
            filterStatusLabel.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            showAllLabel.Visible = true;
            filterStatusLabel.Visible = true;
            filterStatusLabel.Text = filterStatus;
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = logCallBindingSource; 
    }


}
}
```

**Here is the form which performs the adding functionality**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Call_Logger
{
public partial class AddingFunctionality : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    public AddingFunctionality()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
    }

    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        if (comboCallLogBy.Text == "")
        {
            comboCallLogBy.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Name of the person who is logging the call is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboCallLogBy.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboCallType.Text == "")
        {
            comboCallType.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Specification of the type of call is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboCallType.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboCallLocation.Text == "")
        {
            comboCallLocation.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Location of the call is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboCallLocation.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (txtIncidentNumber.Text == "")
        {
            txtIncidentNumber.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the incident number", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            txtIncidentNumber.Focus();
            return;
        }
        else {
            decimal OutNumber;
            if (!decimal.TryParse(txtIncidentNumber.Text, out OutNumber))
            {
                txtIncidentNumber.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
                MessageBox.Show("Value for Incident number should be numerical", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtIncidentNumber.Focus();
                return;

            }

        }

        if (comboCaller.Text == "")
        {
            comboCaller.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Name of the caller is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboCaller.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboCallFor.Text == "")
        {
            comboCallFor.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Name of person the call is made for is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboCallFor.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboAssignedBy.Text == "")
        {
            comboAssignedBy.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Name of the person assigning call is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboAssignedBy.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboForwardTo.Text == "")
        {
            comboForwardTo.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Name of the person call is forwarded to is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboForwardTo.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboContactPerson.Text == "")
        {
            comboContactPerson.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Name of the person contacting is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboContactPerson.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboClosedBy.Text == "")
        {
            comboClosedBy.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Name of the person call closed by is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboClosedBy.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (comboStatus.Text == "")
        {
            comboStatus.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            MessageBox.Show("Status of the call is required", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            comboStatus.Focus();
            return;
        }
        try
        {

            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            command.CommandText = ("insert into LogCall (CallLogBy, CallLogDate, CallLogTime, CallType, CallLocation, ProblemDescription1, ProblemDescription2, IncidentNo, Caller, CallFor, AssignedBy, AssignedDate, AssignedTime, ForwardTo, ContactPerson, ForwardDate, ForwardTime, ActionTaken1, ActionTaken2, NextStep1, NextStep2, ClosedBy, CloseDate, CloseTime, Remarks1, Remarks2, Status) values ('" + comboCallLogBy.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "','" + comboCallType.Text + "','" + comboCallLocation.Text + "','"+ textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + txtIncidentNumber.Text + "','" + comboCaller.Text + "','" + comboCallFor.Text + "','" + comboAssignedBy.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker3.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker4.Text + "','" + comboForwardTo.Text + "','" + comboContactPerson.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker5.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker6.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + comboClosedBy.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker7.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker8.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + comboStatus.Text + "')");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully", "Record Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            con.Dispose();
            this.Hide();
            Dashboard dboard = new Dashboard();
            dboard.ShowDialog();
            con.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            con.Close();
        }




    }

    private void AddingFunctionality_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            string query = "select * from MiscData";
            //string query1 = "select * from Try";
            command.CommandText = query;
            //command.CommandText = query1;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboCallLogBy.Items.Add(reader["CallLoggedBy"].ToString());
                //comboCallType.Items.Add(reader["CallType"].ToString());
                //comboCallLocation.Items.Add(reader["CallLocation"].ToString());
                comboCaller.Items.Add(reader["Employees"].ToString());
                comboCallFor.Items.Add(reader["Employees"].ToString());
                comboAssignedBy.Items.Add(reader["Employees"].ToString());
                comboForwardTo.Items.Add(reader["Employees"].ToString());
                comboContactPerson.Items.Add(reader["Employees"].ToString());
                comboClosedBy.Items.Add(reader["Employees"].ToString());
                //comboStatus.Items.Add(reader["Status"].ToString());

            }
            con.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);

        }

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            string query = "select * from CallType";

            command.CommandText = query;


            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                comboCallType.Items.Add(reader["CallingType"].ToString()+ " " + reader["CallDesc"].ToString());

            }
            con.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);

        }

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            string query = "select * from Location";

            command.CommandText = query;


            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                comboCallLocation.Items.Add(reader["LocationType"].ToString() + " " + reader["Description"].ToString());

            }
            con.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);

        }


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            string query = "select * from Status";

            command.CommandText = query;


            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                comboStatus.Items.Add(reader["StatusType"].ToString() + " " + reader["Description"].ToString());

            }
            con.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);

        }



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Dashboard Add = new Dashboard();
        Add.ShowDialog();
    }








}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us, where the DataSource property of the datagridview is bound to the bindingsource?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz I did that dynamically by adding the database to the gridview on the form designer itself

Comment: Where did you add the new values?

Comment: @TrầnAnhNam that was done in another form which is separate from this particular form. I have added the code for that as well.

Comment: Did you add value to `logCallBindingSource`?

Comment: Is `logCallBindingSource` an observable collection? Does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz no, simply what it does that there is a Form (lets call it A) and there is another form ( lets call it B)
Now in Form A, I add data to a table through the most simplest way

In Form B, I am trying to display that data in a database but the thing is that it does not show me the updated values.

Comment: @Juan Doe Did you fetch data from your database to `logCallBindingSource`?

Comment: Yes I did use that by following this particular method: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx

Comment: If your collection/datasource does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` you have to retrieve and assign it everytime from the database when it is changed.

Comment: @Juan Doe I saw you fetched data from DB once, you need to fetch data to dataSource again to bind to dataGridView. Agree to Sebastian's answer.

Comment: @TrầnAnhNam could you give me an example. I looked for examples using datagridviews but strangely those examples are implementing bindinglists and my implementation does not have a list :/

Answer (score 0):

[`DataGridView.Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) and [`DataGridView.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) are methods that are inherited from Control. So there work is to do with redrawing the control which is why new rows don't appear.

You need to rebind data to `DataGridView` like below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtData; //add you data here
}
```

Comment: So, should I add a button to the form in which the click event would use this code or should I place it somewhere else?

Comment: It's your choice. You can do this right after you are adding new row to `datagridview`

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the code works without any error but still there is no update in the data gridview

Comment: Please update the question and add your changed code

Comment: Edited as per your request